# Windows Store App Certification : Native Image Generation failed

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, app-certification-kit

I built a basic Grid App and tried to run it through Windows App certification kit.
It passed in all criteria save one: Native Image Generation.

Here is the error output from WAC Result:

> "Performance launch
> Error Found: The performance launch test collected the following results:.
> The Native Image Generator failed"

When I tried troubleshooting as described here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2716152

This is what I found in "Performance_Test__trace_Launch*.txt":

> program Information: 0 : 16-12-2012 13:34:54 INFO:[NGenTest]ERROR:  GetCorSvcBindToUnregisteredWorker failed because the worker process died with errorcode -2147221168
>
> program Information: 0 : 16-12-2012 13:34:54 INFO:[NGenTest]ERROR: Failure while compiling: C:\Users\EC\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\BookSiteV1\BookSiteV1\bin\Release\AppX\BookSiteV1.exe
>
> program Information: 0 : 16-12-2012 13:34:55 INFO:[NGenTest]ERROR:  GetCorSvcBindToUnregisteredWorker failed because the worker process died with errorcode -2147221168
>
> program Information: 0 : 16-12-2012 13:34:55 INFO:[NGenTest]ERROR: Failure while compiling: C:\Users\EC\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\BookSiteV1\BookSiteV1\bin\Release\AppX\BookSiteV1.exe
>
> program Information: 0 : 16-12-2012 13:34:55 INFO:[NGenTest]Error occurred while generating compiling at least one assembly.

I further tried to test the same thing using even a blank default grid app. I just opened a new blank grid app and directly debugged it. Still showed the same failure. That does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

What version of ACK you had? It says that on the start of the ACK.

Older ACK versions had this kind of problems. Newest version of ACK is 2.2 and you should only use that one. You can find it from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/jj572486)

Comment: Hey, My ACK is 2.2, the latest one. Still I get this error. Please help.